# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type List`1 but this dictionary requires a model item of type IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

thanks in advance for helping.

New to MVC so is probably easy to answer. I'm getting this error and have no idea what any of it means. This is my code:

**My view:**

```
@model carBayWebsite.Models.WishList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create",
  "WishLists",
  FormMethod.Post,
  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Add to WishList?</h4>
    <hr />
    <p>Are you sure you want to add this to your Wish List?</p>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AdvertId)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AdvertId)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public class WishListsController : Controller
{
    private Entities2 db = new Entities2();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string userName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        var wishlist = from ads in db.Adverts
                      join wish in db.WishLists
                      on ads.AdvertId equals wish.AdvertId
                      where wish.UserId.Contains(userName)
                      select wish;

        return View(wishlist.ToList());
    }

    // GET: WishLists/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        WishList wishList = db.WishLists.Find(id);
        if (wishList == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(wishList);
    }

    public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        else
        { 
        string usID = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
        int adID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        WishList wishList = db.WishLists.Find(id);
        ViewBag.userId = usID;
        ViewBag.advertId = adID;
            return View(wishList);
        }




    }

    // POST: WishLists/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(WishList wishList)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.WishLists.Add(new WishList
            {
                UserId = ViewBag.userId,
                AdvertId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.advertID),
            });
                        try {
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        }

                        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                            {
                                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                                {
                                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                                    {
                                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", 
                                                                validationError.PropertyName, 
                                                                validationError.ErrorMessage);
                                    }
                                }
                            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(wishList);


    }
```

Could anyone figure out what's gone wrong? From looking around, I feel like its something really simple like the first like of the View but I can't pin it down! :)

Error details

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[carBayWebsite.Models.Advert]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[carBayWebsite.Models.WishList]'

Comment: I submitted the view

Comment: In the error message what are the generic type parameters of `List<T1>` and `IEnumerable<T2>`? Are `T1` and `T2` the same type?

Comment: @zgoog no it says wishList does not contain a definition for ToList when I put that in

Comment: @CodeNotFound When I click the Submit input button in the view.

Comment: @erdinger the full error message says : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[carBayWebsite.Models.Advert]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[carBayWebsite.Models.WishList]'.

Comment: So your view requires a collection of `WishList` and you're passing it a collection of `Advert`. Are you passing data to a wrong view?

Comment: @erdinger So from the list of adverts, there is a "Add to WishList" button that goes from my AdvertsController to my WishList controller and passes the ID of the advert. I'm unsure what the implications of doing that are though. (thanks for this)

Comment: Does your `Index.cshtml` for `WishListsController` does in fact expect a collection of `WishList` (check the `@model` in the view)?

Comment: @erdinger the index for WishListController is expecting @ model IEnumerable<carBayWebsite.Models.WishList>

Comment: And you're passing it a collection of `Advert` from the `Index` action (your LINQ query selects `Advert`).

Comment: The error is self explanatory - you passing a collection of `Advert` to a view which has `@model IEnumerable<WishList>` and none of the code you have shown has anything to do with the issue! You need to show the view that has `@model IEnumerable<WishList>` which best guess is `Index()` because you `Index()` method passes a collection of `Adverts`

Answer (score 0):

The view you showed us is `Create` I think.(Because header is 'Create')

You are passing to `Create` view whishList which is type of WhisList `return View(wishList);`

But your view waits for `Advert`  at the start of your view: `@model carBayWebsite.Models.Advert`

I think this is the problem. Let me know if it isn't.

Comment: You were absolutely right that it was wrong, but that was a mistake from me trying to fix it earlier.  Totally forgot to change it back. The error is still exactly the same!